# Union Ranges from Different Workbook in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have learned about the `IMPORTRANGE()` Function and also the simple union of ranges using `{}`. However, what I want to do is to unite multiple ranges from different workbooks.

```
=IMPORTANGE("http:\\LinkOfWorkbook1", "Sheet1!A:A")
```

It works fine but when I tried uniting 2 ranges from different workbooks like

```
={IMPORTRANGE("http:\\LinkOfWorkbook1", "Sheet1!A:A"); IMPORTRANGE("http:\\LinkOfWorkbook2", "Sheet1!A:A")}
```

It doesn't work. Do I have to add a function or whatnot to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify 'it doesn't work'. What error message do you get? Etc.

Comment: It's Formula parse error. My apologies, I forgot to mention the error.

Comment: Does the spreadsheet you're importing into have access to both of the imported spreadsheets? Try importing a range from both, but not in the same formula. If they're both accessible, let me know and we'll try something else. Otherwise, you'll need to 'allow access' to both sheets then try the combined import again.

Comment: Yes. I have an access to both spreadsheets. Thank you.

Comment: Without seeing it exactly, I cannot see an error. I could only suggest checking the quotation marks etc. Sorry I could not help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the problem is that the union of both IMPORTRANGE have too many rows. Try using Sheets1!A1:A1000 instead if Sheets1!A:A

Related

- [Import Range from spreadsheet but exclude rows with missing data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31868144/1595451)
- [consolidate specific row values from different sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41869223/1595451)

Comment: Is there a way to trim the empty rows?

Comment: @aer There are several ways, like using FILTER or QUERY built-in functions.